# how to automatically loop through colors using Random() by simply click a button

Tags: android, android-layout

Am doing a simple application, whereby when the user clicks on the button. the background color will keep changing to different colors using the `Random()`. how can i implement that ? here is my code

```
if (looper == false) 
{
    Jbutton1.setText("loop now ");
    int color;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),                             rnd.nextInt(256));
    JmyScreen.setBackgroundColor(color);
    looper = true;
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "stop loop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Jbutton1.setText("stop looping");
    JmyScreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    looper = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the background of the button getting changed periodically after every 4 seconds.Here you pass the id of your background and check it is work for you or not.
Hope this helps :)

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

        private Runnable mEndlessRunnable;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
            super.onCreate(savedState);
            setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

            mEndlessRunnable = new UpdateRunnable(new Handler(), new Button[] {
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1),
                (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_2)
            });
            mEndlessRunnable.run();

        }

        private static class UpdateRunnable extends Runnable {

            private Random mRand = new Random();
            private Handler mHandler;
            private Button[] mButtons;

            private Button mCurButton;
            private int mState;

            public UpdateRunnable(Handler handler, Button[] buttons) {
                mHandler = handler;
                mButtons = buttons;
            }

            public void run() {
                // select a button if one is not selected
                if (mCurButton == null) {
                    mCurButton = mButtons[mRand.nextInt(mButtons.length)];
                }
                // check internal state, `0` means first bg change, `1` means last
                switch (mState) {
                case 0:
                    mCurButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_bg);
                    mState = 1;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mCurButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellow_bg);
                    // reset state and nullify so this continues endlessly
                    mState = 0;
                    mCurButton = null;
                    break;
                }

                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 4000);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response, in your code your setting the background to a color in a resource folder, but i would like to generate color automatically using color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),
       rnd.nextInt(256));

Comment: why don't you set the color in xml which you want to generate.

Comment: am trying to create an application that will flash a different random color on the screen at a time, when the user clicks a button. And i wanted to make it in away that. the user clicks once. then the application flashes many colors until when the user clicks the stop button.

Comment: try to set color instead of the background in the above code and see what happens.let me knw the result :)